# Sort by Amount of True Booleans?

Tags: mysql

I tried to find this online, but I can't seem to find anything. How would I check for example, for the amount of integers (which = 1) and then sort the rows from most to least?

For example, these three booleans.

INT_ONE, INT_TWO, INT_THRE

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the columns together, and sort on that:

```
ORDER BY (INT_ONE + INT_TWO + INT_THREE) DESC
```

If you also need to use the value:

```
SELECT
  (INT_ONE + INT_TWO + INT_THREE) AS num_true
FROM tbl
ORDER BY num_true DESC
```

This works because booleans in MySQL are 0 or 1.